# Plotting points over raster pixel positions, rather than geographic coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, point, vector

I've been doing some image processing in OpenCV. I have a numpy array which has x1,y1 and x2,y2 coordinates as raster cell positions (so not spatially referenced). I need these coordinates marked off on a raster image, which is spatially referenced in QGIS. Is there a way to plot vector points to raster cell positions?

So to recap I have:

- a raster image I can project properly in a map document
- raster cell coordinates that don't have spatial information

and I want to plot vector points over the raster cell coordinates, not geographic coordinates.

Comment: Would it work if you just remove the georeferencing from the image with gdal_edit? Or by making a copy without georeferencing with GeoTIFF creation option `profile=baseline`? Then the image would have a default geotransform in QGIS, that is 1 unit pixel size and origin at 0,0.

Comment: I think you need to copy the Numpy raster to a new dataset in GDAL and set up a Geotransform. Then you can use the transform to go from pixel coordinates to map coordinates. You need the location of the top left point as origin and the vertical and horizontal spacings.

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution would be to georeference your opencv output before import in QGIS. Transforming the coordinates to your georefenced coordinate system.

I think a way to do it would be to export your georefenced raster in tiff with world file and then take the parameter of your worldfile to process your data with numpy. This way it could be esay and reproducible.

The structure of world file is described in wikipedia : (lien)[https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file]